# Ajax call to a php responds faild to load response

Tags: php, ajax, google-chrome-app

Hi I am developing a chrome application and hosted few files in amazon elasticbeanstalk and send request to that php file through ajax. This is my **ajax** code

```
var dataString = "em=" + email + "&ids=" + ids + "&retrieve";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://xxxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com/retrieve_item.php",
    data: dataString,
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function(data1) {
        var ss = jQuery.parseJSON(data1);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://xxxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com/retrieve_stock.php",
            data: dataString,
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {},
            success: function(datas) {
                if (ss.length == 0) {
                    var sts = "TICKET ID : " + 1;
                    $(".payticket").text(sts);
                } else {
                    var ss1 = jQuery.parseJSON(
                        datas);
                    for (var s = 0; s < ss.length; s++) {
                        var dt = ss[s].ticket_date;
                        var dt1 = dt.split("-");
                        console.log(dt1);
                        var d_day = parseInt(dt1[2]);
                        if (d_day < 10) {
                            d_day = "0" + d_day;
                        }
                        var d_month = dt1[1];
                        var d_year = dt1[0];
                        var ddate = d_year + "-" +
                            d_month + "-" + d_day;
                        console.log(ddate);
                        var todays_date =
                            currentDate.split("/");
                        var t_year = todays_date[2];
                        var t_mnt = todays_date[1];
                        var t_day = parseInt(
                            todays_date[0]);
                        if (t_day < 10) {
                            t_day = "0" + t_day;
                        }
                        var tdate = t_year + "-" +
                            t_mnt + "-" + t_day;
                        console.log(tdate);
                        var gid = ss[s].id;
                        var gids = ss[0].id;
                        var gg = parseInt(gids) + 1;
                        var gg1 = "TICKET ID : " +
                            gg;
                        $(".payticket").text(gg1);
                        if (ddate == tdate) {
                            var stat = ss[s].ticket_status;
                            var cn = ss[s].client_name;
                            var tot = ss1[s].final_total;
                            var tstat;
                            var cls;
                            if (stat == "open") {
                                tstat = "OPEN";
                                cls = "open";
                            } else {
                                tstat = "CLOSED"
                                cls = "open1";
                            }
                            $("#cashreg1").append(
                                '<tr id="' +
                                gid +
                                '"><td><div class="backshadow"><div class="cells1"><div class="titlebar"><label class="ticket">TICKET ID - ' +
                                gid +
                                '</label><label class=' +
                                cls + '>' +
                                tstat +
                                '</label></div><input type="checkbox" class="check_condition" style="display:none;"><div class="whitecontent"><label class="name">' +
                                cn +
                                '</label><label class="close">' +
                                tot +
                                '</label></div></div></div></td></tr>'
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

First ajax responds data but another ajax call on the outer ajax success is failing to respond. Is there something wrong with ajax? I removed dataType='json' and tried adding it also but I did not get any response. 
This is my **php** code

```
$em=$_POST['email'];
 $sid=$_POST['ids'];
$data=array();
$q1="SELECT * FROM `".$em."`.`".$em."_".$sid."_single_item`";
$q = mysqli_query($sql,$q1);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
 $data[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

I return json data. Is there something wrong with the above code?. Can someone please help me?

Comment: what about your query? have you checked and make sure thats right? and what the echoing json_encode($data)?

Comment: it works when I do seperate ajax call to retrieve_item.php @FahrudinYuniwinanto

Comment: what the result of doing alert() in success.  success: function(datas) { alert(datas);}

Comment: chrome application do not allow alert so i use console api by chome application. I get a valid json as return I checked in jsonlint @FahrudinYuniwinanto

Comment: try to make the second ajax in a new function success: function(data1) { retrievingStock(dataString);}

Comment: No I am not getting any response even after having a seperate function @FahrudinYuniwinanto

Comment: first ajax or second ajax of response that you are not getting?

Comment: It second ajax I am not getting a response @f_anto